# Javascript Curry Function Beneficial For This Code?

Tags: javascript, currying

I am new to curry functions and someone suggested I use them. I was wondering with this:

```
var updateNodeStorage;

updateNodeStorage = function(devicesToCheck) {
  var nodesToCallOut;
  nodesToCallOut = devicesToCheck.filter(function(device) {
    var nodeExistInStorage;
    return nodeExistInStorage = nodeStorage.devices.every(function(nodeInStorage) {
      return device.id !== nodeInStorage.id;
    });
  });
  nodesToCallOut.forEach(function(node) {
    getNodeProtocol(node.id);
  });
};
```

Is it beneficial to use a curry function for this code? If so, where and how would I use it?

Comment: Where/why would you apply it? Also, separately, what's the point of the `nodeExistInStorage` variable you declare in the `filter` iterator function?

Comment: `nodeExistInStorage` is a check of devices from user input against a array of of devices that have already been looked up(api call). If it's  in the `nodeStorage` array, don't do a redundant api call.

Comment: Right, but you don't use the variable for anything. You could remove it entirely and just return the result of `nodeStorage.devices.every` without changing what the code does at all (and any half-decent JavaScript engine will do so automatically).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't see anywhere in that code currying would be useful.

[Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is the practice of pre-filling one or more of a function's arguments (sometimes called "partially applying" the function), so that later when the curried function is called, those arguments are passed to the original. Here's an example:

```js
// A boring function
function foo(a, b) {
  snippet.log("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
}

// Create one curried with the value 1 for a using Function#bind
var curriedFoo1 = foo.bind(null, 1);

// Call it
curriedFoo1(2); // "a = 1, b = 2"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

As you can see above, JavaScript's `Function#bind` can be used to curry, but has the issue that it also sets the value used as `this` (that's why the above passes `null` as the first argument to `bind`). JavaScript doesn't have a built-in means of *just* currying without messing with `this`, although it's easy to add one. (PrototypeJS adds a `Function#curry` to functions, for instance.)

Here's an **unoptimized** pure `curry`:

```
if (!Function.prototype.curry) {
    (function() {
        var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
        Function.prototype.curry = function() {
            var curriedArgs = slice.call(arguments);
            var original = this;
            return function() {
                return original.apply(this, curriedArgs.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
            };
        };
    })();
}
```

```js
if (!Function.prototype.curry) {
    (function() {
        var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
        Function.prototype.curry = function() {
            var curriedArgs = slice.call(arguments);
            var original = this;
            return function() {
                return original.apply(this, curriedArgs.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
            };
        };
    })();
}

function foo(a, b) {
  snippet.log("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
}

var curriedFoo1 = foo.curry(1);
curriedFoo1(2); // "a = 1, b = 2"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```